# Character array segmentation error

Tags: segmentation-fault, character-arrays

Why would this get a segmentation fautl?

```
char *c = "dog";
     printf ("char is %c\n", s[0]);    
     s[0]='i';    
     printf ("s = %s\n", s);
```

output:
   char is d
   segmentation fault

Why does it error on the second string? Im just trying to understand it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

char* is a const string, the char in it should be changed liked "s[0]='i'; "
changing the string to a char array will be ok.

```
char s[] = "dog";
printf ("char is %c\n", s[0]);
s[0]='i';
printf ("s = %s\n", s);
```

Comment: I know it will be ok if i did it that way, but why does it internally fault?

Comment: I found this from Wiki, not very familiar with the assem stuff :) " When the program containing this code is compiled, the string "hello world" is placed in the section of the program executable file marked as read-only; when loaded, the operating system places it with other strings and constant data in a read-only segment of memory."